# customised devise fails in cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, devise

I have added to fields to my devise user model (fullname and username). This is my user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :confirmable and :activatable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable  

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :username, :fullname
  # attr_accessor :username, :fullname
end
```

devise works fine and I can access fullname in my views. But cucumber fails for following scenario:

```
Scenario Outline: Creating a new account
    Given I am not authenticated
    When I go to register # define this path mapping in features/support/paths.rb, usually as '/users/sign_up'
    And I fill in "user_email" with "<email>"
    And I fill in "user_password" with "<password>"
    And I fill in "user_password_confirmation" with "<password>"
    And I fill in "user_fullname" with "<fullname>"
    And I fill in "user_username" with "<username>"
    And I press "Sign up"
    Then I should see "Signed in as <fullname>" 

    Examples:
      | email           | password   | fullname | username |
      | testing@man.net | secretpass | man net | net |
      | foo@bar.com     | fr33z3     | foo bar | foo |
```

with this error:

```
...
Then I should see "Signed in as <fullname>"                                                                # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:108

    Examples: 
      | email           | password   | fullname | username |
      | testing@man.net | secretpass | man net  | net      |
      undefined method `fullname' for #<User:0x1057a62e0> (ActionView::Template::Error)
      /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activemodel-3.0.3/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:364:in `method_missing'
...
```

uncommenting

```
attr_accessor :username, :fullname
```

in the model makes cucumber work but in my view I cannot access the attribute fullname any longer - what I am doing wrong ?

**UPDATE**: cucumber does not produce error but the test fails because fullname is not inserted into the database:

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue Feb 01 13:43:17 +0100 2011
  Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"commit"=>"Sign up", "utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{"password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "fullname"=>"foo bar", "username"=>"foo", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"foo@bar.com"}}
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users"."id" FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('foo@bar.com')) LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mAREL (0.3ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "users" ("current_sign_in_ip", "last_sign_in_ip", "created_at", "email", "remember_created_at", "reset_password_token", "password_salt", "last_sign_in_at", "remember_token", "sign_in_count", "current_sign_in_at", "encrypted_password", "updated_at") VALUES (NULL, NULL, '2011-02-01 12:43:18.265015', 'foo@bar.com', NULL, NULL, '$2a$10$DzOCWVM1EHxp7E2asqfw8u', NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, '$2a$10$DzOCWVM1EHxp7E2asqfw8uNDPZifWxbBJA1xbfHh83nF1oOD9RTa6', '2011-02-01 12:43:18.265015')
  [1m[36mAREL (0.1ms)[0m  [1mUPDATE "users" SET "current_sign_in_ip" = '127.0.0.1', "last_sign_in_ip" = '127.0.0.1', "last_sign_in_at" = '2011-02-01 12:43:18.273337', "sign_in_count" = 1, "current_sign_in_at" = '2011-02-01 12:43:18.273337', "updated_at" = '2011-02-01 12:43:18.273724' WHERE ("users"."id" = 1)[0m
Redirected to http://www.example.com/
Completed 302 Found in 325ms
```

I use rails 3.0.3 and newest cucumber/capybara gems

thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You're defining the `fullname` field in the `attr_accessible` list but, by the looks of things, there is no fullname field in your `users` table, nor is it listed in any `attr_accessor` call, like the one you've got commented out.

Thus, undefined method.

Answer (score 0):

ok and thank you. I think I found the problem: I used *cucumber feature/...* which did not work with my migrations.

Using rake cucumber works fine. And now also cucumber feature/... works !?